# Unable to push project from local to git repository set up in AWS : Permission denied (publickey) when try git push production master

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, public-key

I am new to AWS and followed a tutorial to set up git in aws and the push my local files into it. I have a Key with me with .pem extension which got generated while I was creating the instance. I have added the remote repository like this: `git remote add production ssh://root@35.154.37.131/var/repo/site.git`

after this when I tried to push into the repository I got:

```
$ git push production master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: You need to set up an ssh keypair. The `.pem` file has nothing to do with ssh keypairs. Note also that `git push` does not push *files*, but rather *commits*. The receiving Git gets whole commits, not individual files.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify your key which is in the `.pem` to be used when connecting to your server.

Setup an SSH config file in your SSH directory (on Linux / Mac OS this is under $HOME/.ssh/config) and enter an entry similar to this

```
Host 35.154.37.131 
User root
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-private-key.pem
```

Comment: I followed  your instructions and error has resolved . Thank you very much

Comment: Happy to help @surajsingh. Feel free to accept my answer as the correct solution :)